# Cannot drop the statistics 'Table_Name', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server

While dropping a table and recreating we are getting following error:

"Cannot drop the statistics 'dbo.SChema.STATS_table_name', because it
does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: are there any index on this table? what do you see in SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer under `<YourDb> / Tables / <YourTable> / Statistics` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the points you should consider:

1. Check the permissions for the user
2. Check if the stats are not being dropped because of any indexes
3. If you have a pre-written script, check if they are dropped before the script actually runs (may be due to some other scripts, happened with me once :p)

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the table manually and now are trying to add a migration where you trying to remove that table via code (for example you just removed entity class), you also will receive this error. Then you just need to create that table 'Table_Name' manually directly in database. And then again to add migration.